# How to sort column with datetime values in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with the following column (where is more than one column there):

```
camp_data['visit_time']    

39697    2017-12-25 16:19:51
39701    2017-12-25 16:19:48
39708    2017-12-25 16:19:19
39711    2017-12-25 16:19:18
39715    2017-12-25 16:19:32
39717    2017-12-25 16:19:57
39718    2017-12-25 16:19:19
```

I'm trying to sort these values like this:

```
camp_data.sort_values(by=['visit_time'])
```

But they are still unsorted:

```
39697    2017-12-25 16:19:51
39701    2017-12-25 16:19:48
39708    2017-12-25 16:19:19
39711    2017-12-25 16:19:18
39715    2017-12-25 16:19:32
39717    2017-12-25 16:19:57
39718    2017-12-25 16:19:19
```

What is the proper way to sort these values?
They seem to be sorted normally only by date not by time

Comment: `camp_data. = camp_data.sort_values(by=['visit_time'])` or `camp_data.sort_values(by=['visit_time'], inplace=True)` ?

Comment: show full description of this camp_data variable. is it list of strings? list of dictionaries or what?